# Select max or equal value from several columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to select the column with the highest value for each row in a data.frame. So for instance, the data is set up as such.

```
> df <- data.frame(one = c(0:6), two = c(6:0))
> df
  one two 
1   0   6
2   1   5
3   2   4
4   3   3
5   4   2
6   5   1
7   6   0
```

Then I'd like to set another column based on those rows. The data frame would look like this.

```
> df
  one two rank 
1   0   6    2
2   1   5    2
3   2   4    2
4   3   3    3
5   4   2    1
6   5   1    1
7   6   0    1
```

I imagine there is some sort of way that I can use plyr or sapply here but it's eluding me at the moment.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you get the results?

Comment: I want to be able to produce the rank column somehow. So for instance, if df$one > df$two, df$rank would equal 1, df$two > df$one, df$rank <- 2, and df$one == df$two <- 3. But I want to have a more complex set of rules than that, such that if there are three columns, I check if there's total equality(one == two == three), etc.

Comment: What if one and two are equal, and both are greater than three? What if two and three are equal, and less than one? etc., etc. I think you should give an example that's a bit closer to what you actually want, or else you're likely to get many answers that treat special cases/aren't general enough for you.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I think, from his comment, as long as they are both equal, the rank is 3.

Comment: @Arun -- I guess I was just thrown off by the reference to `one == two == three` in the comment above.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I agree it was confusing. Took me a while to understand. raynach, here's a vectorised solution if you're interested: `(sign(df$one - df$two)+2) %% 3 + 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a more efficient solution, but

```
ranks <- apply(df, 1, which.max)
ranks[which(df[, 1] == df[, 2])] <- 3
```

*edit: properly spaced!*

Comment: Thanks, I think this is basically what I need.

Comment: `apply` on a data.frame if it can be avoided, should be. It internally converts to matrix which can be quite time consuming on large data.

Comment: heh, will do! I'm assuming http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html is a good guide.